# Making comparison between dataframe rows for dropping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe, I have a type of data that can be seen below:

```
product_no    part_no    level
1              1_1         1
1              1_2         1
1              1_3         2
1              1_4         1
1              1_5         1
1              1_6         2
1              1_7         1
2              2_1         1
2              2_2         1
3              3_1         2
```

I want to make such comparison that if two succesive rows have the level "1", then the upper row would be dropped. To understand better, after the transformation I intend to make, the output should look like:

```
product_no    part_no    level
1              1_2         1
1              1_3         2
1              1_5         1
1              1_6         2
2              2_2         1
3              3_1         2
```

I already achieved the output via iterating through all the rows, which became extremely painful in terms of time, since the dataframe has overwhelmingly many rows. Any workaround by any other method is also welcome and I am completely open and desperate for help and a solution.

Comment: check drop_duplicates

Comment: I am not looking for duplicates. As you can see, the output I written above has duplicate values in the level column. What I want to create is more specific. Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: It dependes, @nizarcan, is it possible that there are repeating 1s at "level" but "product_no" are different? For instance `df['product_no'] = [4, 5]`while `df['level'] = [1,1]`

Comment: That possibility does not create any harm for my case here, but to articulate my point better, I edited my dataframe to show exactly what I needed, I do not need to consider part_no or product_no in any way. The only thing that matters is that if the current and next level is 1 or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: After @ALollz answer it made me remember the pandas `.shift()` function, so you can do this all from your DataFrame. Pandas works faster if you think of working with columns than rows.

```
## Create Dummy data and dataframe
level=[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
part_no=['1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '2_1', "2_2","2_3", "3_1"]
product_no=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame([product_no, part_no, level]).transpose()
df.columns = ['product_no', 'part_no', 'level']
```

Finally, the code to remove the duplicates

```
# Essencially you'll create 2 columns, a shift of level
# and a compare between this new column and level
df['level2']= df['level'].shift(-1)
df['level3'] = df['level'] == df['level2']
# Than you filter by the oposite as marked as duplicates
## in conjunction of the level values being 1
df= df[~((df.level3)&(df.level==1))]
# then drop the temp columns
df.drop(['level2','level3'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I can't explain how appreciated I am. You two guys just saved me from whole lot of stuff to go through, AND broadened my horizon, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consecutive value groups are created with `ne` + `shift` + `cumsum`. This considers only the `'level'` column.

```
s = df['level'].ne(df['level'].shift()).cumsum()
```

If you only want to consider dropping duplicates for consecutive groups of `level==1`, you can accommodate that by ensuring that each row for any level other than `1` is its own group.

```
s = (df['level'].ne(df['level'].shift()) | df.level.ne(1)).cumsum()
```

To get keep only the last row within group use any of the following:

```
df.groupby(s).tail(1)

df.loc[~s.duplicated(keep='last')]

# Excessive and verbose, but straightforward. 
df.assign(s=s).drop_duplicates('s', keep='last').drop(columns='s')
```

---

```
   product_no part_no  level
1           1     1_2      1
2           1     1_3      2
4           1     1_5      1
5           1     1_6      2
8           2     2_2      1
9           3     3_1      2
```

Comment: This works like a charm, I can not explain how greatful I am at the moment, thanks for your time and effort. Thanks, solved!

Comment: Just noticed, this works exceptionally well in terms of performance with one problem, I only want to delete the rows that has level 1, this code deletes consequent twos, threes as well.

Comment: @nizarcan That is a very simple fix to how you define `s`; see the update. The rest follows unchanged.